# Does ctrl+A delay movement in bushes?

Tags: league-of-legends

Juking around the bushes in the jungle is pretty common where the enemy leaves the bush past you as soon as you enter it.This has led up to people using the ctrl+A method,which allows you to automatically guide your auto attacks within the bush without targeting the champion specifically.

What if the enemy doesnt turn around? What if they run full speed ahead?

Will failure to have a target within the bush delay my movement which in turn may cost me a +1 on my KDR?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the action name of this keybind? Everyone does not have the same. Do you refer to the `Player attack Move` action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There will be no delay. All you have to do is issue the next command for your champion before he reaches the destination of your attack move.

For clarification, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> [Does not exist](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hotkeys_and_commands) as a default action. OP is referring to Attack-Move which is accomplished by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, then clicking where you want to move. This will target and attack the first enemy champion or minion within auto attack range along the path to the destination. If the enemy is killed, you will proceed to the destination point, or kill the next enemy, and so on.

Comment: isn't it the same as shift+click?

Answer (score 4):

The **Player attack move** (if by Jake's opinion is what you asked for) behave this way:

- Moves the player toward the destination
- Movement stops under one of these conditions: an enemy unit is within range or the destination has been reached
- At the end of the movement, if there is a target in range then the player attacks
- At the end of the movement, if there is no target then the player reverts to the waiting state.
- When the target is killed, a new one will be elected

Important mechanic:

- Melee champions seem to have an area of detection which is (at least for Leona) around 2 times it's Auto-Attack normal range. This means that the melee champion will move into fighting position in order to perform the attack, even if this get him away from the move chosen by the player
- For successive attacks, the range seem to be computed from the last position and not the original destination point
- When no more valid target can be found, the champion will return to the original destination point.

This implies two things:

- If the closest enemy unit is a minion, the action will not fire at a champion even if he also is in range
- If the movement stops in a bush with no target in range, the champion will not target any new unit that enters his range in order to stay invisible.

In conclusion, regarding the jungling example you are refering to: attack-moving into a bush will automatically attack the closest valid enemy unit (neutral does not count unless they took damage) in the path. Should the enemy jungler come out of the bush when you enter, your champion will try to initiate an attack (getting in range for a melee champion if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the case in LoL's engine, but I suspect it is. In StarCraft 2, the scenario you're describing exists. Let's say you have a worker (SCV) running away from an enemy unit (Zergling) in the early game. You right-click your worker once to send him to safety, and he survives. Alternatively, you panic and spam right-clicks. The pathing is recalculated each time and they add up, and cause a SLIGHT delay, that actually can cause Zerglings to catch up to your worker and click it.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're wondering if A+move after move-commanding to a bush, can cause a small enough pathing re-calc that you will slow down a FRACTION of a fraction -- but this fraction is big enough to get you out of cc/initiate range. I suspect the answer is YES, *but*, so would right-clicking twice (i.e., the pathing recalculation is indepedent of normal move or a-move).

A-moving is generally a good idea though. Smartcasting a ward mid-path is what I tend to do, if possible, even though it WILL delay your movement a bit, in many cases its worth it.

**Summary**: It is highly-likely, based on the inherent way pathing-calculating engines operate, that every move-command recalculates pathing and adds a slight delay. Each command you stack will set you behind slightly compared to just a single move, but there is no difference between a+move and just move, in terms of "delay."